# ERROR when running Angular app

Tags: angular, webpack

When i start my Angular app `ng serve`

Webpack: Failed to compile.

```
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 6.04 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 605 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.bundle.js (scripts) 1.7 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 572 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 16.7 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts (828,19): ',' expected.
ERROR in ..node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts (828,33): ',' expected.
ERROR in ..node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts (855,19): ',' expected.
ERROR in ..node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts (986,19): ',' expected.
ERROR in ..node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts (986,33): ',' expected.
ERROR in ..node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts (1011,19): ',' expected.
```

May be some ideas to fix it?

I try to install selenium webdriver to dependencies but it not help me.

my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ng serve",
    "build.prod": "ng build ",
    "ng": "ng",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build "
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.7",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "angular2-tag-autocomplete": "^1.2.10",
    "angular2-ui-switch": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "cool-ascii-faces": "1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "tinymce": "^4.8.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.49",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.116",
    "@types/protractor": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.10",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a StackBlitz with your code?

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of old version of typescript. Go the package.json in your project directory and change the typescript version to **2.3.0** or above. Then execute the command "**npm install**" and then try to execute "**npm start**". For more detailed error you can use "**tsc -p src/**"